# Solidity function returns empty array to web3.js

Tags: javascript, solidity, web3js

Solidity function returns a array of string while executed on Remix as well as truffle console while it returns a empty array when called from JS

Solidity code

```
mapping(address => string[]) addressLink;
function getLinks(address a) public view returns (string[] memory)
  {
    return addressLink[a];
  }
```

JS code

```
contract.methods.getLinks(accounts[0]).call().then(res => {
                 console.log(res)
             });
```

truffle console result and expected results when called from JS

```
[ 'QmTiMLN8X4NE4ho5mqJ9t4bJ17JxfMHAFcg3z66f8vdUh1' ]
```

Result on browser console(Actual result)

```
[""]
0: ""
length: 1
```

Comment: if the contract is local? are you sure you already set the string before getting it from web3js?

Comment: Yes the contact is local. I have set the string through web3 and tried to retrieve from console at first which gives the expected result and when called from web3 it returns a empty array

Comment: can you show the complete code? I need to see how you are getting contract from web3.

Comment: cant paste the complete code here. Snippet of getting instance  https://pastebin.com/mrjEmRmm

Comment: https://pastebin.com/vh5A2J6f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in web3.js library. Which has been closed in the latest beta release

Answer (score 0):

You might set the wrong contract address in your javascript code:

```
 const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(
  SimpleStorageContract.abi,
  deployedNetwork && deployedNetwork.address,
 );
```

The second parameter is contract address, see: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#new-contract

Comment: Doesn't help brother even after replacing the second parameter with just the address of the contract (I am getting the address from the generated JSON file so no point of address being wrong ). All my other functions work properly. only this function is returning a empty array